# Kivy presplash in apk ends too early leaving blank screen for a few seconds

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Title pretty much sums it up. I don't think it's because I'm loading too much so it takes time to render since I only create a screen manager and a screen initially. so I have no idea what the cause of this is. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by having only a please wait screen in screen manager initially, and loaded some of the module and data I loaded initially after the screen had been rendered by having a clock.schedule_once inside the on_enter method for a few seconds. the schedule was so that the screen is visible as right after the module and data are loaded, it moves to the next screen.